# How does failure to allocate memory in constructor bubble up

Tags: c++, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to understand what would occur if I failed to allocate memory in a constructor for an object which is itself dynamic.

Example:

Say I am dynamically allocating an object and I am checking whether the object was allocated:

```cpp
Object* object = new(nothrow) Object();
if (object == nullptr) { // handle stuff }
```

Now what if the constructor of the `Object()` allocates a pointer array like so `new int[n]`.

My question is if the pointer array allocation fails. Will that result in `object` being set to `nullptr`? Or is it a distinctly separate case to handle

Any help is appreciated! (Also please no smart pointer / STL alternatives. I want to know how this works)

Comment: No. An exception thrown by the constructor of `Object` will "bubble up", so the `new (nothrow) Object()` will throw. All `nothrow` does is prevent an exception being thrown (e.g. when allocating raw memory) before calling the constructor of `Object`. It doesn't catch an exception thrown by `Object`s constructor and prevent it propagating.  In this case, I would not use `new (nothrow)` - instead use `new Object()` and catch any thrown exception if you need to handle things somehow (but bear in mind that, if an exception is caught, `object` will not exist in the exception handler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case an exception is thrown.

The `new(nothrow)` only means that failure to allocate storage for the object will not throw, it does not place constraint on the object constructor (nor constructors of subobjects).

Comment: Right so an allocation exception would be thrown in the constructor for the pointer array. This exception in the constructor would not bubble up to the allocation of the `Object` and indicate failure to allocate `Object`?